# How long should I maintain cold crash temperature for Witbier?

Tags: cold-crash

I am brewing a Hoegardden clone. I cold crashed for a couple of days and now on the bottling day I am down with fever.

So, can I keep it at 2°C for few more days until I get well? Should I increase the temperature?

Answer (score 4):

To really answer your question, a couple of days more or less will not make a difference.

Actually, you shouldn't cold crash witbier. It is also bottled with its yeast. At serving time, you then make a choice about pouring it clean, or swirling the bottom and adding it to your beer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can keep the temperature for several days, no problem.

The only problem that can cause you is to clarify too much and lose the turbidity that witbier needs.

Glad to be able to help!